# Exists SQL Statement

Tags: sql, exists

I am trying to find all `year` and `caseseqnumbers` in a table where the type is not appellant Rep 1.  The error is coming from the fact that a `year` and `caseseqnumber` can have many rows in the table.  This is what i have tried:

```
Select caseseqnumber, year
from caseparticipants
where not exists (Select *
                  from caseparticipants
                  where participanttype = 'Appellant Rep 1')
```

Any help?!

Comment: Where you say "the error is coming" what happens?  Do you get an actual error message?  If so please tell us which one.  Or just describe what happens (or does not happen).

Comment: i do not get an error message i just end up with no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join caseparticipants with itself, using a LEFT JOIN. If the join doens't succeed, it means that caseseqnumber and year don't have a row with `participanttype = 'Appellant Rep 1'`:

```
SELECT
  c1.caseseqnumber, 
  c1.year 
FROM 
  caseparticipants c1 LEFT JOIN caseparticipants c2
  ON c1.year=c2.year AND c1.caseseqnumber=c2.caseseqnumber
     AND c2.participanttype = 'Appellant Rep 1'
WHERE
  c2.year IS NULL
```

**EDIT**

To compare the number of distinct combinations of caseseqnumber, year, and the number of combinations that have a a type of 'Appellant Rep 1' you could use this SQL Server query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CAST(c1.caseseqnumber AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(c1.year AS VARCHAR)),
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CAST(c2.caseseqnumber AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(c2.year AS VARCHAR))
FROM 
  caseparticipants c1 LEFT JOIN caseparticipants c2
  ON c1.year=c2.year AND c1.caseseqnumber=c2.caseseqnumber
     AND c2.participanttype = 'Appellant Rep 1'
```

Comment: to add to this is there a way to compare the total number of distinct year and cases numbers to these results to get a pecentage?

Comment: @parkjohnston i've updated my answer, i hope it is what you are looking for!

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','. is the error i get.  Also is there a way in which to get the total distinct count of all casenumber and years? i am trying to compare them to get a percentage.

Comment: @parkjohnston ah it works in mysql but probably not on others platforms... what dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server...not sure of the year

Comment: what does the result return? the total number of cases and then the total number of those without a rep?

Comment: @parkjohnston the total number of cases, and the total number of cases that have 'Appellant Rep 1'

Comment: what if i want the total number of cases that dont have a rep 1? I would like the results to be total cases and those without a rep

Comment: @parkjohnston you can use COUNT(...the first count..)-COUNT(..the second count...)

Comment: final question...in both of your above statements...where do i place a yaer statement to limit the results down to a user requested year?

Answer (score 2):

why do you need to do a nested search in there . Nested searches are needed only needed in case of checking things in more than one <strike>database</strike> Table.

stick to

```
select caseqnumber,year from caseparticipants where paticipanttype <> 'Appellant Rep 1'
```

(<> is the sql clause for NOT EQUAL TO)

Comment: _Nested searches are needed only needed in case of checking things in more than one database._ Care to explain that statement?

Comment: That does not work as there are also entries that are just appellant and they could be on different lines. I am looking to find just the cases that have an appellant and NOT a rep

Comment: I feel that they are needed in this situation as if i just ask for a line where the entry is not Appellant Rep 1..i may get another line with that casenumber and year as the Appellant and Appellant Rep are stored on two different lines

Comment: Nested searches are needed only needed in case of checking things in more than one table... lol

Comment: what do you mean that Appellant and Appellant Rep are stored in two different lines?

Comment: what I basically meant with the nested searches thing I said earlier on is that ... if there's no relation in the entity-relationship diagram then there's no need for a nested search. Is there a relationship between appellant and appellant reps?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
    caseseqnumber, 
    year 
from 
    caseparticipants 
where 
    participanttype != 'Appellant Rep 1'
```

Comment: That does not work as there are also entries that are just appellant and they could be on different lines.  I am looking to find just the cases that have an appellant and NOT a rep.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use `WHERE` condition directly in the main query instead of using a sub query?

```
SELECT caseseqnumber, year 
  FROM caseparticipants 
 WHERE participanttype != 'Appellant Rep 1'
```

Comment: That does not work as there are also entries that are just appellant and they could be on different lines. I am looking to find just the cases that have an appellant and NOT a rep

Comment: @parkjohnston - Can you please show your exact data structure and requirement?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LI0XudmDJ1TT4c6yBjMhPioFlgGcqL1GYw8kYYvOFHo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am trying to find the year and case seqnumber where the case does not have an Appellant Rep 1.  It is challenging because the rep and appellant can be stored on different lines

Answer (score 0):

If you want all cases that have an appellant but not a rep:

```
Select caseseqnumber, year
from caseparticipants cp1
where not exists (Select null
                  from caseparticipants cp2
                  where cp2.participanttype = 'Appellant Rep 1'
                  and cp1.caseseqnumber = cp2.caseseqnumber
                  and cp1.year = cp2.year
)
```